# How to trigger events on child instances from parent class in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Following is the code I use to create a custom event emitter.

So that all the classes inheriting the EventEmitter class can emit and listen to events.
Currently the event emission happens only in one way direction.

ie. from child to parent.

(Assuming that both child and parent inherit from EventEmitter class)

```
class EventEmitter {
  listeners = {}
  
  addListener(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    this.listeners[eventName].push(fn);
    return this;
  }

  on(eventName, fn) {
    return this.addListener(eventName, fn);
  }

  once(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    const onceWrapper = () => {
      fn();
      this.off(eventName, onceWrapper);
    }
    this.listeners[eventName].push(onceWrapper);
    return this;
  }

  off(eventName, fn) {
    return this.removeListener(eventName, fn);
  }

  removeListener (eventName, fn) {
    let lis = this.listeners[eventName];
    if (!lis) return this;
    for(let i = lis.length; i > 0; i--) {
      if (lis[i] === fn) {
        lis.splice(i,1);
        break;
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  emit(eventName, ...args) {
    let fns = this.listeners[eventName];
    if (!fns) return false;
    fns.forEach((f) => {
      f(...args);
    });
    return true;
  }

  listenerCount(eventName) {
    let fns = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    return fns.length;
  }

  rawListeners(eventName) {
    return this.listeners[eventName];
  }
}
```

So My requirement is that I want to create a new method called `triggerChild(eventName)` inside this EventEmitter Class Such that when I fire this event on the instance of child from the parent class, a listener which is set inside the children with the eventName will automatically get fired & operates some logic.

Somewhat like this

```
/// parent class

class Parent extends EventEmitter{

constructor() {
this.childinstance = new Child()

this.parentmethod()
}

parentmethod() {
this.childinstance.triggerChild(eventName)
}

}
```

& inside the child instance

```
/// child instance class

class Child extends EventEmitter{

constructor () {
this.on(eventName, () => do some logic)
}

}
```

I could have did something like the following:

```
/// parent class

class Parent extends EventEmitter{

constructor() {
this.childinstance = new Child()

this.parentmethod()
}

parentmethod() {
this.childinstance.runAnyChildMethod()
}

}
```

But this is not What I want. I want to do it in the EventEmitter Way.

**NB** The Real need is a kind of triggering an event from the parent on child instances.

Comment: [https://codeburst.io/event-emitters-and-listeners-in-javascript-9cf0c639fd63]

Comment: @NAO ... your sanitized link ... [codeburst.io :: Event emitters and listeners in JavaScript](https://codeburst.io/event-emitters-and-listeners-in-javascript-9cf0c639fd63)

Comment: Just instead of `triggerChild` call `emit` (which is the method you wrote to trigger events) and it works?!

Comment: However, I don't see why you would need `class`es or inheritance for this - maybe except for the `parentMethod`. Your `Child` should not have a constructor that starts listening to events, at best it should have a separate method to do that. But really you should just write `const child = new EventEmitter(); child.on(…);` (and maybe package it into a function).

Comment: Why is the `Parent`  even an `EventEmitter`? You seem to never emit an event on it. Or more generally, why are `Parent` and `Child` instances even two different objects?

Comment: No. The idea is to create a new method in the EventEmitter class other than what I've wrote, which will an event from parent so that a listener inside child willl be invoked. That's the idea.

Comment: Currently for me event emission is working find ie. it is happening from child to parent & parent listens to the event. Instead I need a method along with this such that I can trigger  same event from the parent such that the child event listener will get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
const EventEmitter2 = require('eventemitter2');

class Parent extends EventEmitter2{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

class Child extends EventEmitter2{
    constructor(parent, name) {
        super();
        this.listenTo(parent, ['foo', 'bar']);
        this.on('foo', ()=> console.log(`(${name}).foo`));
        this.on('bar', ()=> console.log(`(${name}).bar`));
    }
}

const parent= new Parent();

const child1= new Child(parent, 'child1');
const child2= new Child(parent, 'child2');

parent.emit('foo');
parent.emit('bar');
```

Output:

```
(child1).foo
(child2).foo
(child1).bar
(child2).bar
```